# Overflows to right

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using the framer motion library I'm trying give a text animation which it will come from right.When I use x: '-100%' it just dissapears but when I use x: '100%' it goes to the far right of the page instead of dissapearing. I want it to dissapear what can I do?